# MySQL: [Err] 1146 - table 'alias' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for something like

```
SELECT
    `foo`.*,
    (SELECT MAX(`foo`.`bar`) FROM `foo`)
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM `fuz`) AS `foo`;
```

but it seem that `foo` does not get recognized in nested query as there is error like

```
[Err] 1146 - Table 'foo' doesn't exist
```

I try the query above because I think its faster than something like

```
SELECT
    `fuz`.*,
    (SELECT MAX(`bar`) FROM `fuz`) as max_bar_from_fuz
FROM `fuz`
```

Please give me some suggestions.

EDIT: I am looking for solutions with better performance than the second query. Please assume that my table `fuz` is a very, very big one, thus running an additional query getting `max_bar` cost me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What you want, for the first query (with some modification) to work, is called Common Table Expressions and MySQL has not that feature.

If your second query does not perform well, you can use this:

```
SELECT
    fuz.*,
    fuz_grp.max_bar
FROM 
    fuz
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT MAX(bar) AS max_bar
      FROM fuz
    ) AS fuz_grp
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the feature name. I will put some research on it another day :)
On topic: what if the actual query is like

    `SELECT
        fuz.*,
        fuz_grp.max_bar
    FROM
        fuz,
        <a lot of other things like joins, etc.>
      CROSS JOIN
        ( SELECT MAX(bar) AS max_bar
          FROM fuz
          <same a lot of other things like joins, etc.>
        ) AS fuz_grp`

Does the cost me the same just as I do with the later query in the question?

Comment: I think the cost depends on the optimizer (the version of MySQL you use). But up until recently, MySQL would have to execute the same subquery twice, whatever way you write it. Meaning, there was no easy way to write it and perform cleverly (well, except that some internal cache will be used).

Comment: Recent MariaDB versions (5.3 and 5.5) have several optimizer improvements so you may check/test your queries there (improvements like caching subqueries so probably all the above versions, yours and mine, would run faster as they would use the results from one subquery to execute the other one). MySQL 5.6 (when released, still in beta) will have some improvements too.

Answer (score 0):

Alias created into a SELECT clause only can be used to access scalar values, they are **not** synonyms to the tables. If you want to return the max value of a column for all returned rows you can do it by running a query before to calculate the max value into a variable and then use this variable as a scalar value into your query, like:

```
-- create and populate a table to demonstrate concept
CREATE TABLE fuz (bar INT, col0 VARCHAR(20), col1 VARCHAR(20) );
INSERT INTO fuz(bar, col0, col1) VALUES (1, 'A', 'Airplane');
INSERT INTO fuz(bar, col0, col1) VALUES (2, 'B', 'Boat');
INSERT INTO fuz(bar, col0, col1) VALUES (3, 'C', 'Car');

-- create the scalar variable with the value of MAX(bar)
SELECT @max_foo:=MAX(bar) FROM fuz;

-- use the scalar variable into the query
SELECT *, @max_foo AS `MAX_FOO`
FROM fuz;

-- result:
-- | BAR | COL0 |     COL1 | MAX_FOO |
-- |-----|------|----------|---------|
-- |   1 |    A | Airplane |       3 |
-- |   2 |    B |     Boat |       3 |
-- |   3 |    C |      Car |       3 |
```

Comment: I think this is just what I do with the later query in the question, right? But thank for creating and populating sample data :D

Comment: Well... maybe the suggestions are equivalent. I am not a MySQL specialist, but sometimes the query planner doesn't take the shortest path and there might be conditions when MySQL will run the inner query for each row of the outer query, leading to what can be a significant overhead. Using a scalar variable will never incur into this situation ;)

Answer (score -1):

Just simple use MAX function:

```
SELECT
    `fuz`.*,
    MAX(`fuz`.`bar`)
FROM
    `fuz`
```

or if you use

```
SELECT
    `foo`.*,
    MAX(`foo`.`bar`)
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM `fuz` JOIN `loolse' ON (`fuz`.`field` = `loolse`.`smile`)) AS `foo`;
```

Comment: you have extra `(`. And there is no need `AS` when specified alias

Comment: Where did that `loolse` come from?

Comment: @ypercube, i think topic starter post not realy some query, and i show one of way for use table alias in from section

Comment: @Sergey I'm not steal your message but correct syntax. If it's caused offense I'm sorry, now message has deleted.

Comment: @Sergey : I think with the same database, our queries' result will be different. Mine will show all the records from `fuz` with an extra column `max_bar`, but yours will show only the first row plus `max_bar`